# Issue with stack navigators nested within separate tabs of an app in react native expo

Tags: react-native, navigation, stack-navigator

I have an app with 5 tabs. In each tab I want to have a separate stack. I have one stack that works fine, and now when I have introduced a second stack the new one doesn't work, however the original stack still works fine. This is the error.

" ERROR  Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render."

The code for the first stack navigator that works:

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
import AddSession from '../../screens/addSessionScreens/AddSession'
import InSession from '../../screens/addSessionScreens/InSession'
import LogClimb from '../../screens/addSessionScreens/LogClimb'

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

const SessionStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: true
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="New Session" component={AddSession} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Climbs This Session" component={InSession} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Log Climb" component={LogClimb} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default SessionStack
```

The code from these screens:
Add Session:

```
const AddSession = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.wrapper}>
      <Logo />
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <MyButton
          title="New Session"
          onPress={() => navigation.push('Climbs This Session')}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

In Session:

```
const LogClimbScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item style={item.style} grade={item.grade} attempts={item.attempts} />
  )
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.wrapper}>
      <Logo />
      <View style={styles.textButtonContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.timeStyle}>Time in session: HH:MM</Text>
        <MyButton
          title="Log Climb"
          onPress={() => navigation.push('Log Climb')}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.listWrapper}>
        <FlatList
          data={climb}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
          ListEmptyComponent={<Empty />}
          ListHeaderComponent={<Header />}
        />
      </View>
      <MyButton title="End Session" onPress={() => alert('Hello World')} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

The stack that doesn't work:

Convert Stack

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
import GradeConverter from '../../screens/convertScreens/GradeConverter'
import Convert from '../../screens/convertScreens/Convert'

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

const ConvertStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: true
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="Convert Grade" component={GradeConverter} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Convert" component={Convert} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default ConvertStack
```

Grade Converter:

```
const GradeConverter = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.wrapper}>
      <Logo />
      <View style={styles.ropeButtonContainer}>
        <MyButton title="Rope" onPress={() => navigation.push('Convert')} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.boulderButtonContainer}>
        <MyButton
          title="Boulder"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Convert')}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

I'm new to react native so not sure why one works and one doesn't, they are In separate tabs of the overall app.js file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the components I was importing both had the stack named "Stack", gave them both unique names and this fixed the bug.